# Elminar duplicados de una tabla en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Como puedo eliminar datos duplicados de una tabla, ya intente con este codigo pero no me deja eliminar los duplicados

```
    delete a
    from prueba1 a
    left join (SELECT min(id) as id, username, count('')
        FROM prueba1
        group by username
        having count('')>1) b on a.id =b.id and a.username =b.username
    where b.username is not null
    and a.id<> b.id
```

me arroja este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: DELETE [no recibe](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) nombres de tablas.

Comment: En todo caso sería `delete prueba1 from prueba1 ...`